# How to deal with XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

What is the best way to deal with XML documents, XSD etc in C# 2.0?

Which classes to use etc. What are the best practices of parsing and making XML documents etc.

EDIT: .Net 3.5 suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: For those also trying to find a more workable solution, ignore this. It's old an .NET library. Use XDocument instead, and you'll save gouging your eyes out in frustration

Answer (score 187, accepted):

The primary means of reading and writing in C# 2.0 is done through the **XmlDocument** class. You can load most of your settings directly into the XmlDocument through the XmlReader it accepts.

#### Loading XML Directly

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<People><Person Name='Nick' /><Person Name='Joe' /></People>");
```

#### Loading XML From a File

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(@"C:\Path\To\xmldoc.xml");
// Or using an XmlReader/XmlTextReader
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Path\To\xmldoc.xml");
document.Load(reader);
```

I find the easiest/fastest way to read an XML document is by using XPath.

#### Reading an XML Document using XPath (Using XmlDocument which allows us to edit)

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<People><Person Name='Nick' /><Person Name='Joe' /></People>");

// Select a single node
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("/People/Person[@Name = 'Nick']");

// Select a list of nodes
XmlNodeList nodes = document.SelectNodes("/People/Person");
```

If you need to work with XSD documents to validate an XML document you can use this.

#### Validating XML Documents against XSD Schemas

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidateType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add("", pathToXsd); // targetNamespace, pathToXsd

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(pathToXml, settings);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

try {
    document.Load(reader);
} catch (XmlSchemaValidationException ex) { Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

#### Validating XML against XSD at each Node (UPDATE 1)

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidateType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add("", pathToXsd); // targetNamespace, pathToXsd
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(settings_ValidationEventHandler);

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(pathToXml, settings);
while (reader.Read()) { }

private void settings_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    // e.Message, e.Severity (warning, error), e.Error
    // or you can access the reader if you have access to it
    // reader.LineNumber, reader.LinePosition.. etc
}
```

#### Writing an XML Document (manually)

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(pathToOutput);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("People");

writer.WriteStartElement("Person");
writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "Nick");
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteStartElement("Person");
writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
writer.WriteValue("Nick");
writer.WriteEndAttribute();
writer.WriteEndElement();

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();

writer.Flush();
```

***(UPDATE 1)***

In .NET 3.5, you use XDocument to perform similar tasks. The difference however is you have the advantage of performing Linq Queries to select the exact data you need. With the addition of object initializers you can create a query that even returns objects of your own definition right in the query itself.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);
    List<Person> people = (from xnode in doc.Element("People").Elements("Person")
                       select new Person
                       {
                           Name = xnode.Attribute("Name").Value
                       }).ToList();
```

***(UPDATE 2)***

A nice way in .NET 3.5 is to use XDocument to create XML is below. This makes the code appear in a similar pattern to the desired output.

```
XDocument doc =
        new XDocument(
              new XDeclaration("1.0", Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName, String.Empty),
              new XComment("Xml Document"),
              new XElement("catalog",
                    new XElement("book", new XAttribute("id", "bk001"),
                          new XElement("title", "Book Title")
                    )
              )
        );
```

creates

```
<!--Xml Document-->
<catalog>
  <book id="bk001">
    <title>Book Title</title>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

All else fails, you can check out this MSDN article that has many examples that I've discussed here and more.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468556.aspx

Comment: You may want to point out that you're using XDocument in the last example as XDocument is quite different to XmlDocument

Comment: Correction; there is no C# 3.5; you mean .NET 3.5 and C# 3.0

Comment: oh, and the "on the fly" [object initializers] would work largely the same with C# 3.0 and XmlDocument - still a good answer, though (+1)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if you are loading a document to query with XPath (and not to edit) then using an XPathDocument will be a lot more efficient

Comment: Is this Schema Validation done node by node? If not, is there a way to do it node by node?

Comment: This answer is precisely the "how-to, in brief" that I needed to get going quickly. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like ValidateType in XmlReaderSettings  is now "ValidationType" in .Net 5 and .net framework 4.7.2 and newer.

Answer (score 32):

It depends on the size; for small to mid size xml, a DOM such as [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (any C#/.NET versions) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (.NET 3.5/C# 3.0) is the obvious winner. For using xsd, You can load xml using an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), and an XmlReader accepts (to [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx)) an [XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx). The XmlReaderSettings objects has a [Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx) property that can be used to perform xsd (or dtd) validation.

For writing xml, the same things apply, noting that it is a little easier to lay out content with LINQ-to-XML (XDocument) than the older XmlDocument.

However, for huge xml, a DOM may chomp too much memory, in which case you might need to use XmlReader/XmlWriter directly.

Finally, for manipulating xml you may wish to use [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) (an xslt layer).

The alternative to working with xml is to work with an object model; you can use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) to create classes that represent an xsd-compliant model, and simply load the xml *as objects*, manipulate it with OO, and then serialize those objects again; you do this with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: To manipulate(add/suppr elements) a big XML document (40k lines). What's the best way ? I used to use LINQ-to-XML.

Answer (score 12):

nyxtom's answer is very good.  I'd add a couple of things to it:

If you need read-only access to an XML document, `XPathDocument` is a much lighter-weight object than `XmlDocument`.

The downside of using `XPathDocument` is that you can't use the familiar `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` methods of `XmlNode`.  Instead, you have to use the tools that the `IXPathNavigable` provides:  use `CreateNavigator` to create an `XPathNavigator`, and use the `XPathNavigator` to create `XPathNodeIterator`s to iterate over the lists of nodes you find via XPath.  This generally requires a few more lines of code than the `XmlDocument` methods.

But:  the `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode` classes implement `IXPathNavigable`, so any code you write to use those methods on an `XPathDocument` will also work on an `XmlDocument`.  If you get used to writing against `IXPathNavigable`, your methods can work against either object.  (This is why using `XmlNode` and `XmlDocument` in method signatures is flagged by FxCop.)

Lamentably, `XDocument` and `XElement` (and `XNode` and `XObject`) don't implement `IXPathNavigable`.

Another thing not present in nyxtom's answer is `XmlReader`.  You generally use `XmlReader` to avoid the overhead of parsing the XML stream into an object model before you begin processing it.  Instead, you use an `XmlReader` to process the input stream one XML node at a time.  This is essentially .NET's answer to SAX.  It lets you write very fast code for processing very large XML documents.

`XmlReader` also provides the simplest way of processing XML document fragments, e.g. the stream of XML elements with no encluding element that  SQL Server's FOR XML RAW option returns.

The code you write using `XmlReader` is generally very tightly coupled to the format of the XML it's reading.  Using XPath allows your code to be much, much more loosely coupled to the XML, which is why it's generally the right answer.  But when you need to use `XmlReader`, you really need it.

Comment: Note that there is an extension method [`XPathNavigator CreateNavigator(this XNode node)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299124.aspx) to create an `XPathNavigator` from an `XNode` (which includes the derived class `XDocument`).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, get to know the new **XDocument** and **XElement** classes, because they are an improvement over the previous XmlDocument family.

1. They work with LINQ
2. They are faster and more lightweight

**However**, you may have to still use the old classes to work with legacy code - particularly previously generated proxies. In that case, you will need to become familiar with some patterns for interoperating between these XML-handling classes.

I think your question is quite broad, and would require too much in a single answer to give details, but this is the first general answer I thought of, and serves as a start.

Comment: I agree they (XDocument etc) are great, but the OP asked about C# 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

101 Linq samples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

and **Linq to XML samples**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688087.aspx

And I think Linq makes XML easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in .NET 3.5 and you aren't affraid of experimental code you can check out LINQ to XSD (http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2008/02/21/linq-to-xsd-alpha-0-2.aspx) which will generate .NET classes from an XSD (including built in rules from the XSD).

It then has the ability to write straight out to a file and read from a file ensuring that it conforms to the XSD rules.

I definately suggest having an XSD for any XML document you work with:

- Allows you to enforce rules in the XML
- Allows others to see how the XML is/ will be structured
- Can be used for validation of XML

I find that Liquid XML Studio is a great tool for generating XSD's and it's free!

Answer (score 2):

Writing XML with the XmlDocument class

```
//itemValues is collection of items in Key value pair format
//fileName i name of XML file which to creatd or modified with content
    private void WriteInXMLFile(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> itemValues, string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = "C:\\\\tempXML\\" + fileName + ".xml";
        try
        {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(filePath);                   

                XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Documents");

                XmlNode pageNode = doc.CreateElement("Document");
                rootNode.AppendChild(pageNode);


                foreach (string key in itemValues.Keys)
                {

                    XmlNode attrNode = doc.CreateElement(key);
                    attrNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(itemValues[key]);
                    pageNode.AppendChild(attrNode);
                    //doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(attrNode);

                }
                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pageNode);
                doc.Save(filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                using(System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                {
                    //Do nothing
                }

                XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("Documents");
                doc.AppendChild(rootNode);
                doc.Save(filePath);

                doc.Load(filePath);

                XmlNode pageNode = doc.CreateElement("Document");
                rootNode.AppendChild(pageNode);

                foreach (string key in itemValues.Keys)
                {                          
                    XmlNode attrNode = doc.CreateElement(key);                           
                    attrNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(itemValues[key]);
                    pageNode.AppendChild(attrNode);
                    //doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(attrNode);

                }
                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(pageNode);

                doc.Save(filePath);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

OutPut look like below
<Dcouments>
    <Document>
        <DocID>01<DocID>
        <PageName>121<PageName>
        <Author>Mr. ABC<Author>
    <Dcoument>
    <Document>
        <DocID>02<DocID>
        <PageName>122<PageName>
        <Author>Mr. PQR<Author>
    <Dcoument>
</Dcouments>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a typed dataset in the designer then you automatically get an xsd, a strongly typed object, and can load and save the xml with one line of code.

Comment: I've had great success with DataSet's.  They are also very friendly with Databases.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion, as a C# programmer, is that the best way to deal with XML in C# is to delegate that part of the code to a VB .NET project.  In .NET 3.5, VB .NET has XML Literals, which make dealing with XML much more intuitive.  See here, for example:

[Overview of LINQ to XML in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx)

(Be sure to set the page to display VB code, not C# code.)

I'd write the rest of the project in C#, but handle the XML in a referenced VB project.

Comment: It's not worth to swtich to vb only for XML literal. XML only deal with literals. If the xml is passed in as a parameter, XML literal support doesn't give you much benefits. Instead, the legacy syntax of vb.net will ruin the happy programming experience of C#.

Answer (score 0):

Cookey's answer is good... but here are detailed instructions on how to create a strongly typed object from an XSD(or XML) and serialize/deserialize in a few lines of code:

[Instructions](http://www.stevehorn.cc/#!/blog/generate-code-from-xml-schema-xsdexe)

Comment: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." :(

Answer (score 0):

nyxtom,

Shouldn't "doc" and "xdoc" match in Example 1?

```
XDocument **doc** = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);
List<Person> people = (from xnode in **xdoc**.Element("People").Elements("Person")
                   select new Person
                   {
                       Name = xnode.Attribute("Name").Value
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I've submitted an edit for approval on the answer you're referring to, however this should really have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks David. Agreed, it wouldn't allow me to comment at the time. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to convert data between `XmlNode` <=> `XNode` <=> `XElement`
(e. g. in order to use LINQ) this Extensions may be helpful for you:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static XNode GetXNode(this XmlNode node)
    {
        return GetXElement(node);
    }

    public static XElement GetXElement(this XmlNode node)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = xDoc.CreateWriter())
            node.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        return xDoc.Root;
    }

    public static XmlNode GetXmlNode(this XElement element)
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
    }

    public static XmlNode GetXmlNode(this XNode node)
    {
        return GetXmlNode(node);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlDocument MyXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
MyXmlDocument.Load("MyXml.xml");
XElement MyXElement = MyXmlDocument.GetXElement(); // Convert XmlNode to XElement
List<XElement> List = MyXElement.Document
   .Descendants()
   .ToList(); // Now you can use LINQ
...
```