# Process xml without loading into memory

Tags: c#, .net, xml

What is the best way to process XML if I can't afford to load the whole file into memory?

Comment: In general terms, a "SAX parser" processes the file as it's read, while a "DOM parser" loads the whole document.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML#Benefits

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and process element by element.

Comment: +1 This is the right idea. Note however, that `XmlReader` is an abstract class. If you are reading character data, you probably want to use an `XmlTextReader`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class, it doesn't load the whole document into memory. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220867/how-to-deal-with-xml-in-c) you can find the complete list of ways to deal with XML with examples and pros and cons for every technology used.