# Reading text data with multiple delimiters, storing in an array, and displaying in multiple text boxes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, textbox

I am a first time poster, long time reader.

I have finally come across a problem that I cannot seem to find an answer to, and would love the help of the community to solve it!

So, the problem: I have this data (small excerpt)  -

```xml
<region name="GLOBAL">
<light_dir_mult> 0.0020 0.0005 3.1000 10.0000 21.0000 22.9900 27.9900 29.5500 25.0660 18.0000 3.2000 1.0000 0.0099</light_dir_mult>
</region>

<region name="URBAN">
<light_dir_mult> 0.0020 0.0005 3.1000 10.0000 21.0000 22.9900 27.9900 29.5500 25.0660 18.0000 3.2000 1.0000 0.0099</light_dir_mult>
</region>
```

What I would like to be able to do, is load this data from a file, search for the 13 values between the open/close tags, and store them in 13 text boxes. This would need to be done twice for each "URBAN", and "GLOBAL" regions.

Additionally, after the values have been loaded into the text boxes, they would then need to be added back to the file with the exact same format they originated in. (After being edited by the user.)

I have devised a C# windows form solution, utilizing tabs to display the data based on regions. However, I have no idea how to properly search the file and store the 13 values accordingly :/

(**The reason the values need to be stored in a text box, is due to the nature of the application. Its sole purpose is to provide an interface to edit these data files. Although the example provided shows one set of open/close tags, the original file contains thousands of different tags, and thus this process will need to be repeated multiple times, under different conditions.**)

If anyone can think of an elegant solution to this problem, I would love to hear it!

EDIT:

Here is basically what I have so far, just simply loading the file.

```
private void loadFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            file.Title = "Open the xml weather file.";
            file.Filter = "XML files|*.xml";
            file.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file.FileName.ToString());
            }

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FileName);
```

From here, I would need to find a way to search the file (using some sort of delimiter?) down to each "region" tag, then each "light_dir_mult" tag, then down again to separate each value. After I can manage to store each of the 13 values, they would then need to transferred into sperate textboxes.

Comment: Can you show any of your code otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: You should research "serialization of data to xml file". There is a lot of material on stack overflow with the same situation as you are in

Comment: I have updated the post to provide the little I have so far, and what steps I "think" should be taken next.

Comment: I have updated the post to provide the little I have so far, and what steps I "think" should be taken next. I will look into serialization of data to xml in the meantime! Thank you

Comment: Yep, any XML parser that's convenient for you should do just fine. Read a few XML solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220867/how-to-deal-with-xml-in-c-sharp

Comment: And once you get the text value of your `<light_dir_mult>` node, simply do a `.Split(new char[] { ' '})` to get those values as an array. To write them back as one space-delimited string, use `string.join(" ", valuesArray)`

Comment: Never load the data direct into textboxes or any other control. Seperate your tasks (reading, editing, writing) and start building a structure that can hold the data. Now write a reader that fill that structure, then write an editor to edit the structure and finally a writer to write the structure back