# Is it possibile to add a new work item type through custom extension or REST API?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-sdk

I'd like to know if in a custom process template is possibile to add:
- new work item type 
- new field in pre-existing work item type
through custom extension (to be developed by me) and/or REST-API?

More specifically, my question is related to the fact that in Azure DevOps Server 2019, using xml process template, is possible to add new work item type and/or new field only programming in xml or is also possible to add them through custom extension (to be developed by me) and/or REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inherited process templates, you can manage work item types,fields with REST API:

1. [Work Item Types - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work%20item%20types/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
2. [Fields - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
3. [States - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

For xml process, you can work through xml definition of work item type:

1. Export some basic work item type with witadmin [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops-2019)
2. Change xml file with your custom code (through [XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220867/how-to-deal-with-xml-in-c-sharp) or as text): change the name, add field..... [XML element reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/xml-element-reference?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)
3. Import it back [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=azure-devops-2019)