# how to read an XML file and grab all URL links in it and save them to a TXT file ? C#

Tags: c#

I have an .XML file (This is a LOG that my program made) with this text in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PsnRecords>
  <PsnRecord>
    <Names></Names>
    <PsnUrl>http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/ppkgo/prod/CUSA05330_00/108/f_acb1a312a982305e284718898b3dade6afb395e6718d836b1d7b1e1aa1873800/f/EP0953-CUSA05330_00-BRAWLHALLAEUROPE-A0403-V0100-DP.pkg</PsnUrl>
    <LocalUrl>C:\Users\Betrisa\Desktop\Shared\EP0953-CUSA05330_00-BRAWLHALLAEUROPE-A0403-V0100-DP.pkg</LocalUrl>
    <isLixian>false</isLixian>
    <LixianUrl></LixianUrl>
  </PsnRecord>
  <PsnRecord>
    <Names></Names>
    <PsnUrl>http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/ppkgo/prod/CUSA05330_00/108/f_acb1a312a982305e284718898b3dade6afb395e6718d836b1d7b1e1aa1873800/f/EP0953-CUSA05330_00-BRAWLHALLAEUROPE-A0403-V0100.pkg?downloadId=0000015b&amp;du=000000000000015b00e26bd28904ee7f&amp;product=0187&amp;serverIpAddr=192.168.137.1&amp;r=00000000</PsnUrl>
    <LocalUrl></LocalUrl>
    <isLixian>false</isLixian>
    <LixianUrl></LixianUrl>
  </PsnRecord>
  <PsnRecord>
    <Names></Names>
    <PsnUrl>http://ic.97f46e00.060798.gs2.sonycoment.loris-e.llnwd.net/gs2/ppkgo/prod/CUSA05330_00/108/f_acb1a312a982305e284718898b3dade6afb395e6718d836b1d7b1e1aa1873800/f/EP0953-CUSA05330_00-BRAWLHALLAEUROPE-A0403-V0100.pkg?downloadId=0000015b&amp;du=000000000000015b00e26bd28904ee7f&amp;product=0187&amp;serverIpAddr=192.168.137.1&amp;r=00000001</PsnUrl>
    <LocalUrl></LocalUrl>
    <isLixian>false</isLixian>
    <LixianUrl></LixianUrl>
  </PsnRecord>
</PsnRecords>
```

I want to get all URL links and save them to a .TXT file.
I tried in 2 ways but they did not work:

**Way 1 : using Split (Result is : Url )**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string paths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\DataHistory.xml";
            string resPaths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\Links.txt";
            StreamWriter urlsWrite = File.CreateText(resPaths);


            var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(paths);
            var links = text.Split("\t\n ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(s => s.StartsWith("<PsnUrl>http://") || s.StartsWith("<PsnUrl>https://"));

            foreach (string s in links)
            {
            urlsWrite.WriteLine(s);     
            }
            
        }
```

**Way 2 : using Regex (Result is Nothing !!)**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string paths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\DataHistory.xml";
            string resPaths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\Links.txt";
            StreamWriter urlsWrite = File.CreateText(resPaths);


            var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(paths);
            var regex = new Regex(@"\b(?:http?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection mactches = regex.Matches(text);
            
            foreach (string matc in links)
            {
            text = text.Replace(matc.Value, "<PsnUrl>"+matc.Value+"</PsnUrl>");
            urlsWrite.WriteLine(mats);     
            }
        }
```

I want a .TXT file with clean URLs in it, like:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use some proper means of parsing XML. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220867/how-to-deal-with-xml-in-c-sharp) to get started.)

Comment: When you asked this earlier today I suggested looking into *XPath*. As everyone else has suggested, treat XML as XML. It is designed to be easily parsed by XML parses.

Comment: @Flydog57 i am new on this site ! and the Admins colsed my post cuz of the rules ! so thank you and others for the helps , you are right Parse XML is the easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way 0: parse XML properly

```cs
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(text);
foreach(var n in doc.SelectNodes("//PsnUrl/text()"))
    urlsWrite.WriteLine(n);
```

Your sample XML seems to be copied from a tree view. Here is the proper content. Note that `&`s are encoded as `&amp;`. If your source does not do so, you could replace them first, e.g. `text.Replace("&", "&amp;")`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PsnRecords>
    <PsnRecord>
        <Names/>
        <PsnUrl>http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/acpkgo/prod/CUSA00803_00/9/f_72955662ebee69bf3f1bbec8b1f1dfef1ed000acb6f96046b394d69fc8551fe4/f/UP0002-CUSA00803_00-CODAWDIGITALPACK.pkg?downloadId=000000ab&amp;serverIpAddr=87.248.195.254&amp;country=us&amp;downloadType=ob&amp;q=1817303785a54ecb464ab93233801c33225a5dae976d075973acb9669874c74b</PsnUrl>
        <LocalUrl></LocalUrl>
    </PsnRecord>
    <PsnRecord>
        <Names/>
        <PsnUrl>http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/appkgo/prod/CUSA00803_00/3/f_6ee0d43dc4ea9a53a9f3d83fe26c7afcfadca8d17795762ab81cb2ddc6086776/f/UP0002-CUSA00803_00-CODAW00000000000_0.pkg?downloadId=000000ac&amp;serverIpAddr=87.248.195.254&amp;country=us&amp;downloadType=ob&amp;q=1817303785a54ecb464ab93233801c33225a5dae976d075973acb9669874c74b</PsnUrl>
        <LocalUrl></LocalUrl>
    </PsnRecord>
</PsnRecords>
```

---

**Unless the XML is malformed, avoid playing with strings yourself.**

Way 1: you need to strip away `<PsnUrl>` and `</PsnUrl>`.

```cs
foreach (string s in links)
    urlsWrite.WriteLine(s.Replace("<PsnUrl>", string.Empty).Replace("</PsnUrl>", string.Empty));
```

Way 2: `mactches`, `links`, `mats`??? please post actual code that compiles. Your replace call is wrapping the URL with the tag!? That is contrary to what you want to achieve.

```cs
foreach (Match matc in mactches)
    urlsWrite.WriteLine(matc.Value);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake !! XML file edited by my duplicate remover ! any way i edited the XML example in first post

Comment: This Parse XML not working 
```
   var paths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\DataHistory.xml";
            string resPaths = Application.StartupPath + @"\DataFiles\Links.txt";
            StreamWriter urlsWrite = File.CreateText(resPaths);


            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(paths);

            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("PsnRecords/PsnRecords/PsnUrl");

            foreach (var n in nodeList)
                urlsWrite.WriteLine(n);
```